# Can't get JQuery .load to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know there are a lot of questions on this subject, but i can't seem to get my load function to work, even with all those answers out there.

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me!

The idea is to load the `#minibox div` from the given URL into a div with the ID of `#dophtml`

the links have this form: http://dop.derbigum.com/index.php?page=&fol=/V1111_VAEPLAN%20V-FR/DE

then i like to add the value &showtemplate=false to the link to reduce the server load (i only need the bare minimum HTML), so i prevent the default click action
add the "&showtemplate=false" part. next i also add the div i want `.load()` to filter out `#minibox` and i call the `.load` function to wrap it up.

I tried 2 methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modalmydop a').on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var posturl = $(this).attr("href") + "&showtemplate=false" + " #minibox";
        $('#dophtml').load(posturl);
    });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modalmydop a').on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var posturl = $(this).attr("href") + "&showtemplate=false" + " #minibox";
        $.load(posturl, function(data){
            $('#dophtml').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Both methodes don't do anything.
i fiddled around https://jsfiddle.net/rezium/oztj1313/22/
but i'm getting nowhere.

is .load() not the right api for the job?
or does my link contains conflicting elements?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: ```Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/rezium/oztj1313/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://dop.derbigum.com/index.php?page=&fol=/V1105_VAEPLAN%20ABS/DE&showtemplate=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.```

Comment: I get the above error in the dev console.

Comment: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; **the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol** - From the load api.

Jquery api - [link](https://api.jquery.com/load/)
WIkipedia - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Have tried this code having both the jquery script and the target page under the same domain ? Maybe in a local installation ?

Comment: this is the page i intend to use it on: http://vaeplan.com/download/dokumente#dop

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.js:5375:0
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://dop.derbigum.com/index.php?page=&fol=/V1111_VAEPLAN%20V-FR/DE&showtemplate=false. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>